# Parse PHP SDK - fixed issues with ParseUser::loginWithFacebook

Tags: php, facebook, parse-platform, sdk

About Parse PHP SDK, and Facebook login, there is a bug I fixed in ParseUser::loginWithFacebook method.

First there is an issue with the namespace, so you get an error due to the namespace on DateTime.
So you can define your own expiration date (simple workaround to fix that):

```
$expiration_date = new DateTime();
$expiration_date->setTimestamp(time() + 86400 * 60);
ParseUser::loginWithFacebook($id, $token, $expiration_date));
```

Then, in ParseUser.php, you also need to modify loginWithFacebook that way (adding authData key):

```
$data = ["authData" => [ "facebook" => [
                "id" => $id, "access_token" => $access_token,
                "expiration_date" => ParseClient::getProperDateFormat($expiration_date)
            ]]];
```

and add json_encode call on the $data argument :

```
$result = ParseClient::_request("POST", "/1/users", "", json_encode($data));
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: This seems like an answer. Would you mind please update the question describing the issue and create an answer with the code you're providing? That will clarify this question and will help the rest. Thanks.

Comment: Yes, this is a fix that I share with the community. I've updated my post the best I can.

Answer (score 0):

Appears Fosco fixed it in his latest version of PHP-SDK . Just  get the latest version from https://github.com/ParsePlatform/parse-php-sdk .

Answer (score 0):

If anyone needs an example of how to do it, here it is:

```
$userLogin = ParseUser::logInWithFacebook($userId, $session);
$userLogin->set("email", $userEmail);
$userLogin->set("name", $userName);
$userLogin->save();
```

Hope this helps.